# jQuery plugin for playing video files of different extension

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I want to know a plugin which can be used for playing video files of different extensions. Here I am passing a video file path from the database. I was confused and never used this..

Already I tried `<embed>` but it does not work for me.

```
<embed id="ShowVideo" allowscriptaccess="always"
    autostart="false" src="@viewVideo" controller="true" 
    allowfullscreen="true" width="280" wmode="transparent" height="200">
</embed>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Which formats are the videos? Do you have access to the video files and can re-encode them if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

just try http://flowplayer.org/

it's an awesome player with many options to customize

Comment: This might not help at all with "different extensions", since Flowplayer only supports MP4, WEBM and OGG formats.

Comment: other formats aren't possible with html5, flowplayer includes a fallback flashplayer for other formats like flv

Comment: ...leaving wmv, mov, mpeg, avi and all other possible formats hanging. The question never specified what format the videos are in nor HTML5 as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for the `embed` tag, it started out being the Netscape video tag but today all modern browsers support the `object` tag. If you plan on playing HTML5 supported video you should use the `video` tag.

You could determine by the file extension if the video is a HTML5 supported format and display the supported tag:

**HTML5 Video**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

**For other formats: object (with embed included for Netscape-compatability)**

```
<object data="movie.wmv" width="320" height="240">
  <embed src="movie.wmv" width="320" height="240">
</object>
```

**For maximum browser support with HTML5 video: Combine the two**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
  </object> 
</video>
```